# Insert an image on LaTeX in a specific location

Tags: image, latex

I'm using an online editor, ShareLaTeX, to implement a project in which I would like to take a specific slide from a PowerPoint lesson provided by the professor and comment down below. The problem now is: using this

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{3_9.png}
\end{figure}
```

the editor puts the figure in a place decided by itself, but I really need to have the specific pic and then the text.
So I used this:

```latex
\\ 
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{3_9.png}
\\
```

but in the final pdf it gives me a duplicate of the name of the image, the pic in the right place like the text and a ton of errors.

Answer (score 2):

Ciao! Have you tried

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
```

instead of

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

as from the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures)?

Comment: Hi! It didn't work.. I have just tried your suggestion

Comment: @218141if you post more of your code, specifically: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that then we can try to replicate and solve! Feel free to update your question rather than add code in comments

Answer (score 2):

I have just resolved the problem by adding a package:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

and using always:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

Wish this could be helpful to someone else!

Comment: Good! This is why a "minimal working example" is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a bad behavior to force Latex to put things in a specific location, as you are asking. In case you truly need it, you can try to use the [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package for absolute positioning of figures or text boxes. [Here](https://nxg.me.uk/dist/textpos/textpos.pdf) you can find a small guide.